# How to configure dependencies in startup using the options pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In ASP.NET Core ConfigureServices Startup method you can do things such as

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true))
        };
    });
```

I want to do something like this on startup to configure my own dependency.

```
services.AddTest(options =>
    new TestOptions
    {
        TestNumber = 8
    });
```

This is my extension method that chains onto `IServiceCollection`...

```
public static IServiceCollection AddTest(this IServiceCollection services, Action<TestOptions> options)
{
    services.AddScoped<ITest, Test>();

    if (options != null)
    {
        services.Configure(options);
    }

    return services;
}
```

and my `TestOptions` is just a simple model...

```
public class TestOptions
{
    public int? TestNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then, finally I pass those options through to the constructor of the class I want to use them...

```
public Test (IConfiguration configuration, IOptions<TestOptions> options)
{
    LocalTestNumber = options.Value.TestNumber;
}
```

However, when I hit the breakpoint on `LocalTestNumber = options.Value.TestNumber` the TestNumber is null and I'm not sure why, anyone have any insight on this?

I followed this tutorial to do this... https://codeburst.io/options-pattern-in-net-core-a50285aeb18d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this part of the code you've shown:

> ```
> services.AddTest(options =>
>     new TestOptions
>     {
>         TestNumber = 8
>     });
> ```

Instead of creating and returning a new instance of `TestOptions`, which gets discarded, configure the `options` argument that gets passed in. Here's the fixed version:

```
services.AddTest(options => options.TestNumber = 8);
```